# Out of memory for very simple SQL query

Tags: php, sql

I have this code:

```
        <?php
    require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/framework/classes/DBConnection.php');

    define('DB_NAME', 'thename');
    define('DB_HOST', 'thehost.com');
    define('DB_USER', 'user');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pwd');




// Connect to database
function db_connect() {
    return DBConnection::GetConnection();
}


function getMeta($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT order_ref FROM orders LIMIT 0,1";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($ref);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close();
    return $ref;
}

function getMeta2($conn, $page) {
    $sql = "SELECT meta FROM pages_meta WHERE pageid = ?";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('s', $page);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($meta);
    $stmt->fetch();
    $stmt->close(); 
    return $meta;
}


$conn = db_connect();
?>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
<?php echo getMeta($conn); ?>
<br>
<?php echo getMeta2($conn, "homepage"); ?>
</body>
</html>
<?php
$conn->close();
?>
```

Output:

```
    Hello World

1407324725

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 209715200 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4294967296 bytes) in /home/rnsalarm/co2supermarket.co.uk/test.php on line 41
```

Huh???!  I get an out of memory exception when running this SQL:

SELECT meta FROM pages_meta WHERE pageid = ?

The table only has 15 rows, and even then it has indexes.  Any ideas what's going on?  The rest of the website works fine, just this one query it throws a wobbler.  To add some more mystery; it works fine if I run in on my local dev computer, connecting to the same DB, only when it's uploaded to the server do I get this problem.  It's very odd.  Like I say, the rest of the website works absolutely fine.

Any thoughts what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah ha!  The datatype was longtext - seems my host doesn't like longtext - changed to a varchar instead and voila!